# Why csrf token and session id are not returned when login with requests into instagram

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, instagram

I'm using python requests to login to instagram account and scrape some accounts, but I haven't been able to connect to Instagram for a week now because neither csrf token nor session id are returned.

```
link = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
login_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
s = requests.Session()
times = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
response = s.get(link)
csrf = re.findall(r"csrf_token\":\"(.*?)\"",response.text)[0]
print("cookies ",response.cookies.get_dict())
```

the output is:

```
{'mid': 'XXXXXXXXXXX'}
```

then I tried to call login post api:

```
payload = {
    'username': login,
    'enc_password': f'#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:{times}:'+password,
    'queryParams': {},
    'optIntoOneTap': 'false'
}

login_header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "Referer": 'https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/web_profile_info/?username=',
    "x-csrftoken": csrf,
    "X-IG-App-ID": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
}
login_response = s.post(login_url, data=payload, headers=login_header, allow_redirects=True)
print("cookies ", login_response.cookies.get_dict())
```

the output is:

```
{'ds_user_id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'mid': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'}
```

it doesn't contains neither csrf token nor session id.
can you help please?

Answer (score 1):

I made a programm to automatically signup on instagram using requests, from what i understood when i investigated instagram signup system is that instagram give you your **csrf token** when you accept the cookies. To get the cookies you can send a GET requests to this url:
*https://www.instagram.com/api/v1/web/data/shared_data/*

You will then get your **csrf token** in *s.cookies.get_dict()*:

```
{
  'csrftoken': 'SOUjtW1N5wLWWJgQfyQHwedZdMaeTrSZ', 
  'ig_did': '1991178D-1CE1-4BD8-BCD4-5B4B0B4D7884', 
  'mid': 'Y57o6AALAAHICZz_hkRc4rE5ULa0'
}
```

You can then easily extract the token.